# Dots goes to commas in PHP Range loop results when put into HTML select drop down list options

Tags: php, html, loops, drop-down-menu, foreach

I have a simple php loop;

```
$array = range(1.00, 1.50, 0.01); foreach ($array as $result)
```

Now the result always comes as 1.1, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03 goes up to 1.50 which i need. But i have to put the results in a HTML Select as Values.

This is what i get in the Select Values;

```
<select name="discount">
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1,01">1,01</option>
<option value="1,02">1,02</option>
<option value="1,03">1,03</option>
and goes on up to 1,50
```

As you can see the issue is with the Commas. PHP returns DOT after 1 but when its inside the option values and texts, it becomes COMMAS.

Below is my code and html;

```
<select name="discount">
<option value="0">No Discount</option>

<?php $array = range(1.00, 1.50, 0.01); foreach ($array as $x) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
```

What could be the reason? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing the locale settings. Have a look at [localeconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) to check your current settings and [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) for setting them.

Comment: kinda looks like a bug in the range function, DOCS say they only need to be positive numbers, which these are, but it seems to go wacko when using decimals.. cough.. set step to 1, and multiply values by 100 ? :/  ugh

Comment: i have tried your code am not getting problem it showing me value in Dots and text in Dots both no Commas any where, check your php version may be thats the issue

Answer (score 1):

**Description** I have tested your code i have no issue you may see in attachment the output. Check your php version may be thats the issue. My PHP Version is 5.6.14. More over if you are using any js files and libraries to enhance your interface, are they causing any errors, because at times these errors leads to un-even behaviours.

[image]

Comment: I just checked the same thing. Code is ok. I'm using a template with bootstrap and many .js libraries inside it. I'm digging them now to see if they effect it. On the same server with same settings i made a plain select form and it worked ok with Dots.

Comment: Yes it could be the reason because errors in some. js files and included libraries can cause some disturbance in UI.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT.. ALSO REMOVE LEADING ZERO from step value ..

Try this wrapping the values in single or double quotes...

```
<?php $array = range('1.00', '1.50', '.01'); foreach ($array as $x) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for output:

```
<?php echo number_format($x,2,".","");?>
```

Comment: number_format is not working too. That is a strange problem. When i echo to result anywhere out side select drop down it comes with Dot not Comma. Inside input and text fields are ok too. Only in select values and texts are with Comma.